# How to make part of string BOLD in R markdown? Output is as html_document

Tags: r, r-markdown

[I am looking for a way so that the word "drumming" is in bold and rest of the remaining string in normal font.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWDge.png)

[This is how I am entering this data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7JOE.png)

As I am new to R,I am not able to find a way to make 'drumming' bold as well as remove these strong styles that are being displayed.

drumming it is reading from a filtered dataframe...zing has a column Area where entry has "drumming" value...I want this to work as a loop....whatever the area it takes in the filtered dataframe has to be displayed in bold...I cant specifically write drumming...I think it needs to be used in cat,paste,strong commands ....I just wanted to know what are the ways in which text can be diplayed in bold using these commands

[This is the datatable which it is reading this drumming from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3B5H.png)

Comment: There is not "drumming" in your second link where you claim you enter data.
Please give a minimal working example with the stackoverflow interface and not with screen shots.

Comment: drumming it is reading from a filtered dataframe...zing has a column Area where entry has "drumming" value...I want this to work as a loop....whatever the area it takes in the filtered dataframe has to be displayed in bold...I cant specifically write drumming...I think it needs to be used in cat,paste,strong commands ....I just wanted to know what are the ways in which text can be diplayed in bold using these commands

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect this. 
Please also include an example of your data frame.
Rewriting it here has many benefits. It makes you reflect and rethink, and it is more legible for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

To mark text bold with *r-markdown*, and in fact also *common markdown* and *pandoc-markdown*, put two *** around the part of the text you want to highlight.  As in **drumming**.

Have a look here

- https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdfhttps://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/
- https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/

Comment: drumming it is reading from a filtered dataframe...zing has a column Area where entry has "drumming" value...I want this to work as a loop....whatever the area it takes in the filtered dataframe has to be displayed in bold...I cant specifically write **drumming**...I think it needs to be used in cat,paste,strong commands